# Variable TweenLite is not defined. - probably path issue?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, gsap

Im currently getting the following error:

"ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable TweenLite is not defined."

I might think its because tweenlite isnt imported correctly, so some path issue - but tried a few things, and still the same.

Basically I have my main.fla, where I import a class:

path: main.fla / classes / com / myfolder / contact / ContactForm.as

AS: import classes.com.myfolder.contact.ContactForm;

In this package I try and import the tweenlite librabry with the following:

```
package classes.com.myfolder.contact
{
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import com.greensock.easing.Quad;
....
}
```

path to tweenlite: main.fla / classes / com / greensock

Any ideas ?

Comment: Could you show us the code where you try to use TweenLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Set your class path to the include the 'classes' directory.
2. Get rid of the classes directory and have the 'com' directory at the same level as main.fla.

I would go with #2 as it's convention to name packages after URLs, plus if someone else uses your code (or you switch computers) you won't have to set the class path all over again.

Your new layout would look like this:

```
main.fla
com
  greensock
  myfolder
    contact
```

Comment: Hey Kreek - ive changed my structure pr advise in your nr. 2 - posted a commnet about it above, but still doesnt seem to work correct for me - any ideas?

Comment: @user688913 Hey I made you a quick example you can download it here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3504731/ClassExample.zip

You'll see it has `com.example.Main.as` which is set as the Document class, in that class TweenLite is imported and tweens a movieclip on the stage. Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

you doing it wrong! :)

if in your main src directory is `classes/Class.as`.

then it's package name will be: `package classes`.

for `classes/content/Main.as`.

you will be having: `package classes.content`

since `TweenLite` has a root package `com`, the root directory of the packages needs to be `com` in your main src directory:

src
|- classes
|- com

The compiler imports the clases from the main src directory, and the class package needs to be the same as the directory it is in.

if you will not prefer to work like this then you will be needing to change all packages names inside the `Tweenlite` from `package com.greensock` to `classes.com.greensock`. which i think is crazy.... :)

you really need to refigure your project structure.

Comment: Hi Jevgenij - thanks for your explanation. Perhaps im just fried today, but it seems im not that far off? Now I have a structure which looks like this: ive removed my classes folder and now have com in root as main. So now I do: import com.myfolder.contact.ContactForm; and have package com.myfolder.contact { import com.greensock.TweenLite; import com.greensock.easing.Quad; } But still doesnt seem to work

Comment: can you attach the zip or something with the .as and .fla files how are you structuring things?